# I have created my module in odoo 15 by code , it is working well but what if i do changes in that module using GUI , the changes remain saved or not?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-15

For example I created one action in my custom addon by using by developer option GUI , so does it got saved automatically in my code ?

Answer (score 2):

No, it won't be saved in your code.

For actions and views and other data provided/initialised by your code/modules it depends on the "update" attribute of the xml id (`ir.model.data`) if changes on the GUI will stay or be changed again on module update.

But there is no feature in Odoo writing back changes to code. Even Odoo Studio changes (Enterprise feature) are saved in the database.